# AT command sent SMS received as Flash SMS (Class 0 SMS)

Tags: wpf, sms, at-command

I used [this link](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/) to send SMS with AT command in WPF.
But when I send SMS with CMGS command, the receiver get the SMS as Flash SMS not usual SMS. My code is as below:

```
 //Check if modem allows you to send and receive SMS messages using AT commands, without the need to decode the binairy PDU field of the SMS first
        rval = sp.SendCommand("AT+CMGF=1");

        //set Text mode parameters 
        rval = sp.SendCommand("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,16");

         string phonenumber = "xxxxxxxxxxx";      
        string Message = "test";

        rval = sp.SendCommand("AT+CMGS=\"" + phonenumber + "\"");

        if (rval.Equals("\r\n> "))
        {
            rval = sp.SendCommand(Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) );

        }
```

and my SendCommand is as below

```
  public string SendCommand(String commandText)
    {

        if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvents.InLogFile(ex.Message);
                throw new Exception("COM port is busy");
            }
        }

        try
        {
            serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            buff = "";
            serialPort.Write(commandText + "\r");
            Thread.Sleep(serialPort.ReadTimeout);
            return buff;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error connection");
        }
    }
```

Can any one help me?

My other references:
[developershome](https://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp), 
[Sayeda Anila Nusrat](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85636/Introduction-to-AT-commands-and-its-uses)

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter in `AT+CSMP` sets the coding scheme, i don't remember in which document i've found the coding of this byte but bit 7 sets whether the message should be discarded after showing it `class 0` or stored

You should set this bit to 1 to make it storable, so changing

```
rval = sp.SendCommand("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,16");
```

to

```
rval = sp.SendCommand("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,144");
```

should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Bit 0 (i.e., the least significant bit) of the fourth parameter of the AT+CSMP command is a flag for whether the SMS will be flashed (when 0) or saved (when 1).

Simply put: An even number for 4th parameter will NOT save the message, while an odd number will.

Answer (score -1):

Change `AT+CSMP=17,167,0,16` to `AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21010333)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It looks like an answer to me (although I can't judge its correctness).

Comment: there's a thin line between answer & comment. This "answer" is more a comment, because no explanation is given on how that would fix it. That's just my point of view.